# C++ Call a specific function if type is a derived type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a wide variety of small component structs with wildly different signatures, data, etc.

struct A, struct B, struct C.

Usually, I'd like each to have a system class free each of these types using templates:

```
static void Free(Component<T>* c)
{
    if (c)
    {
        staticDataPool->Free(c);
    }
}
```

These would correspond to pools created with templates of types A, B, and C.

What I'd like to do is derive a few of them from DestroyableComponent such that when Free() is called. All DestroyableComponents would have a virtual function called Destroy().

```
static void Free(DestroyableComponent* d)
{
    if (d)
    {
        d->Destroy();
        staticDataPool->Free(d);
    }
}
```

In the end, if the class is derived from DestroyableComponent it calls the second version of Free(), if it's not it calls vanilla Free().

Is there a way to do this without all component structs having to derive from something?

Comment: First you said "What I'd like to do is derive a few of them from `DestroyableComponent`" and then you asked "Is there a way to do this without all component structs having to derive from something?" I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: For instance, struct A and B would not be derived from DestroyableComponent; only struct C would be. During the call to Free() C would use the version that called d->Destroy(). The others would not.

Comment: You can accomplish that with function overloading, as long as it doesn't introduce an ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Free(Component<T>* c)
{
     DestroyableComponent* p = dynamic_cast<DestroyableComponent>(c);
     if(p == NULL) //p is not destroyable
     {
          //free static stuff
     }
     else
     {
          //free destroyable stuff
     }
}
```

May I also add that run-time type conversion (RTTI) is slow, so I would seriously think about your design. If I need to detect an object that was allocated on the heap, I overload new and delete for the class, and add a bool destroyable. If delete sees the object is destroyable, it deallocates. Otherwise, it does nothing.

Comment: What does the empty dynamic_cast() do?

Also, Free() is not a member of these component classes, but a larger management system class.

Comment: This throws a compiler error (C2683). On cases where template T is not a polymorphic type, it does not allow you to pass in a pointer to that type into dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MaybeDestroy(DestroyableComponent* d) { d->Destroy(); }
void MaybeDestroy(...) {}

void Free(Component<T>* c)
{
    if (c)
    {
        MaybeDestroy(c);
        staticDataPool->Free(c);
    }
}
```

If `Component<T>` inherits from `DestroyableComponent` then the first overload of `MaybeDestroy` is a better match. The other will be used as fallback if it doesn't inherit from `DestroyableComponent`.